# Sums of squares

Tags: number-theory

> Let $R(n)$ be the number of ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2 = n$. Using the identity $$(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2 =2(a^2 +b^2),$$
>   prove that for all integers $n$, $R(2n) = R(n)$.

I'm not really sure how to start this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with $R(2n)=R(n)$ ?

Comment: the first approach in the problems of such type is to establish bijection between the two representations. The formula you mentioned will help you to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$A(n)=\{\,(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2\mid x^2+y^2=n\,\}$$
so that $R(n)=|A(n)|$.
Show that $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,x-y)$ gives you a bijection $A(n)\to A(2n)$. The identity from the hint shows that this indeed maps elements of $A(n)$ to elements of $A(2n)$ as required. Why is it injective and surjective?

Comment: So $(x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 = n$  but by the relationship given this equals $2(x^2 +y^2) = 2n$ hence A(n) -> A(2n) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume a solution $(x_1,y_1)$, so 
$$
x_1^2+y_1^2=n
$$

use the identity to obtain a solution of $x^2+y^2=2n$. Using the fact that this was an arbitrary solution ...

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even and $$n = x^2 + y^2$$ for integers $x$ and $y$, then $$\frac{n}{2} = (\frac{x+y}{2})^2 + (\frac{x-y}{2})^2,$$ (using the mentioned identity) and both these terms are integers, as $x$ and $y$ must have the same parity.
On the other hand, if $n$ is an integer with $$n = a^2 +b^2$$ for integers $a$ and $b,$ then $$2n = (a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2.$$ Hence if $n$ is even, we can replace $n$ by $\frac{n}{2},$ and $R(n)$ doesn't change.